# How to access SQLite3 native API with SOCI?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, soci

I am currently using SOCI with SQLite3. Everything was working fine until I got to the point that I needed to call a native SQLite3 function in order to enable loading custom extensions into my database (http://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html). Here is the code I am using:

```
sqlite3_session_backend* backend;
backend = static_cast<sqlite3_session_backend *>(databaseSession.get_backend());
sqlite_api::sqlite3* db = backend->conn_;
sqlite_api::sqlite3_enable_load_extension(db, 1);
```

It gives me a segmentation fault at runtime when it reaches the last line of code. I have used a debugger to check if the pointer the backend is returning is valid, and it is. I have also tried calling other native SQLite3 API functions, and they all result in segmentation fault. What am I missing here? These are the includes in my code:

```
#include <soci.h>
#include <soci-sqlite3.h>
```

I have also tried to include sqlite3.h, but it gives the same result. I am using clang++. Any ideas?